# Using cat, head, tail, and tr with pipelines

Tags: linux, bash, unix, pipeline

Trying to do this little exercise. It's not for homework or anything, but I want to make sure I understand it.

> Create 2 files. `file1` will have 4 lines of text. `file2` will have 6 lines of text. Create a pipeline that will print the last 2 lines of `file1` and the first 3 lines of `file2`. Transliterate all lowercase characters to uppercase in `file1` and all uppercase characters to lowercase in `file2`.
>
> Use **no temporary files.**
>
> Use command grouping at the start of the pipeline with two `tr` commands.

And my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

i=0;
while [ $i -lt 4 ]
do
    echo "line $i of file1";
    i=`expr $i + 1`;
done > file1

i=0;
while [ $i -lt 6 ]
do
    echo "LINE $i OF FILE2";
    i=`expr $i + 1`;
done > file2

{
    tr [:lower:] [:upper:] < `cat file2 file1 | tail -2`;
    tr [:upper:] [:lower:] < `cat file2 file1 | head -3`;
}
```

I feel like this is close, but I keep getting the `ambiguous redirect` error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

change the order

```
cat file_1 file | tail -2 | tr ...
```

or do process substitution

```
tr ... <(cat ... | tail ..)
```